# Comment Table Giving SQLSTATE[42S02] laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to make an forum where the user can post a Thread and on the bottom of the thread the user can comment to thread but when I add the commenting part to the thread it throws the `SQLSTATE[42S02]` Error I am trying to use Morph relation ships from laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships so I can connect the thread to the corresponding thread or comment. and the final product has to be someting like Reddits one http://prntscr.com/mwvors where comment go under each other and comment can be commented on other comments.

Edit:
after `php artisan migrate` it updated the the migrations but give this error instead

Error

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.commmentable_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `comments` where `comments`.`commmentable_id` = 1 and `comments`.`commmentable_id` is not null and `comments`.`commmentable_type` = App\Thread) (View: C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel Projects\Forum\resources\views\thread\single.blade.php
```

single.blade.php

```
 {{--Answers/comments--}}
<div class="comment-list">
    @foreach($thread->comments as $comment)

        <h4>{{$comment->body}}</h4>
        <lead>{{$comment->user->name}}</lead>

    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="comment-form">
    <form action="{{ route('threadcomment.store', $thread->id) }}" method="post" role="form">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <h4>Create Comment</h4>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="body" id="" placeholder="Input...">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

user model

```
 public function threads(){
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
}
```

thread model

```
 public function user()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}

public function comments()
{

    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class,'commmentable');

}
```

comment model

```
 public function commenttable()
{

    return $this->morphTo();

}

public function user()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}
```

comment controller

```
  public function addThreadComment(Request $request, Thread $thread)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'body' => 'required|min:10|max:250'
    ]);

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->body = $request->body;
    $comment->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $thread->comments()->save($comment);

}
```

web.php

```
 Route::resource('comment','CommentController', ['only' =>['update','destroy']]);
 Route::post('comment/create/{thread}','ThreadController@storeComment')->name('threadcommment.store');
```

Comment: Have you created the migration for the comments table and run `php artisan migrate`? It sounds like the table does not exist.

Comment: I indeed forgot and updated the post but it keeps throwing an SQL error

Comment: Okay, so now does the column `commmentable_id` exist in the table? You may need to specify the column names. The function definition for `morphMany` is `public function morphMany($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null)`, so you may need to pass in the id and localKey variables.

Comment: add the docs the One To One (Polymorphic) that you dont have to pass anything thru as long as you have `$table->integer('commentable_id');` and `$table->string('commentable_type');` and i have these 2 in mine migrations because it says i will take both of them [Docs laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

there where typos in the code

```
 public function comments()
 {
 return $this- >morphMany(Comment::class,'commmentable');
 }

  Route::post('comment/create/{thread}','ThreadController@storeComment')->name('threadcommment.store');
```

triple MMM instead of 2 mm